# Downloading xls file from application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, rubygems, spreadsheet

I am using spreadsheet gem to generate a xls file in my applications public folder and then using the send_file method to send the file.
My code worked properly on my local machine in test as well as production mode.
But when I deployed this code on heroku it showed the following error:

Permission denied - /app/public/history_23.xls

Can anyone suggest the solution please.

Comment: If this would be ASP.NET I would write my own ASHX handler to fetch the XLS on the server and stream it to the client; i.e. do not provide the client directly with the XLS but through an extra page/handler. Maybe something like this is possible in Ruby, too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Heroku has a read only file system, you CANNOT write to any where except the tmp and log directory -

http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/read-only-filesystem